# SVG with embedded script to scale to browsers available space

Tags: javascript, browser, svg, zooming, scale

I am trying to create a completely self contained SVG document that, when loaded in web browser, automatically scales and centers to the available space. Note that this is *not* about an SVG inside a html document.

Here is the document into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.2"
    width="600"
    height="400"
    docname="web-business-card.svg">
```

So the SVG document's inner dimensions are 600x400 and this is my embedded script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    var fitObject = function() {
      var svg  = document.documentElement;
      var zoom = Math.min((window.innerWidth/600),(window.innerHeight/400));
      var left = parseInt(((window.innerWidth-(600*zoom))/2)/zoom);
      var top  = parseInt(((window.innerHeight-(400*zoom))/2)/zoom);
      // set dynamic style attributes
      svg.style.zoom = zoom;
      svg.style.left = left+'px';
      svg.style.top  = top+'px';
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fitObject);
    window.onresize = fitObject;
  /* ]]> */
</script>
```

This works pretty well in the Chromium browser I used for tests, but completely fails in other browsers. Can anyone guide me to understand what the issue is and how I can resolve it?

Comment: What mime-type is the document?

Comment: @RobertLongson Hm, I currently load the document from the local file system, so no mime type is specified. When delivered via an http server that once specifies `image/svg+xml`. I added the document intro to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that SVG documents can automatically scale themselves to their parent containers without the need for any scripting?

You just need to specify a `viewBox` attribute.

So, for your example, set `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` and add `viewBox="0 0 640 400"`.

Now, when loaded, the SVG should automatically scale to the browser window.

Comment: INteresting, no I did not know that, I just only start to explore non trivial things with SVG. Works fine in Chromium, but again: does not work in Firefox.

Comment: OK, seems like my only issue was that FF shows a completely different behavior when using its zoom feature. Unlike Chromium it does scale the content visibly, Chromium always adjusts the svg to the current zoom level, so that the content does _not_ appear to be scaled at all. Since that feature in FF has a memory it appeared as if the automatic scaling did not work. But indeed it does. Only the behavior afterwards is, well, questionable. Anyways, this is the right solution! Thanks!